# doing something when specific ajax request finish

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I Have many ajax request , and i want to doing some code when one of them exactly finish , but $.when not working correctly , how i can doing that correctly ?

```
getData();
$.when().done(function()
    //doing something here
);

function getData(){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '1.php',
        data:'',
        dataType: 'json',
        success:function(data_Object){

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: you should put the code you want to run inside the `success` property of the ajax request

Comment: When I make that I face error Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function @Simon Staton

Answer (score 3):

You need to pass something into $.when() which can be your ajax call or a deferred object http://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/

try something like this:

```
$.when(getData(), getData2()).done(function(data1, data2){
    console.log("do stuff with", data1);
    console.log("do stuff with", data2);
);

function getData() {
    return $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '1.php',
        data: '',
        dataType: 'json'
    });
}

function getData2() {
    return $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '2.php',
        data: '',
        dataType: 'json'
    });
}
```

You can also handle your callback in the success method:

```
function getData2() {
    return $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '2.php',
        data: '',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data){
            console.log("its finished", data);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use .when if you don't want to.

```
getData(doSomething);

function doSomething(data){
  //do something with data object
}


function getData(callback)
{
    $.ajax
    ({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '1.php',
    data:'',
    dataType: 'json',
    success:function(data_Object)
        {
          callback(data_Object)
        }
     });
}
```